# Is it possible to use carriage return \r without overwriting already written text?

Tags: c, carriage-return

Let's say I have printed  `Welcome` in my console. If I use

```
printf(" Welcome");
printf("\rHello world.");
```

I only get `Hello world.` Is there any special command to get `Hello world. Welcome` without printing Hello world and then Welcome. Basically, I want carriage return without overwriting the text. Is this possible in C?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish. What do you mean by "overriding"? What do you want to do? Why do you feel you need a `\r`? Did you mean to write `\n` instead?

Comment: What you are asking for is a console with "insert mode", so that `Welcome` is moved to the right as `Hello World` is output.   As best I know, that does not exist.

Comment: *"Is this possible in C?"* -- this behaviour is not specific to a language; this is how the terminal works. The carriage return character sends the cursor to the beginning of the line. The next print operation will overwrite the characters already existing there (if any).

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not possible in ANSI C. Assuming you want this to be ANSI C, you will have to print `"Hello, World."` first and then print `" Welcome"`.

Otherwise, there are various solutions, including curses. See mevets's answer for a curses solution.

Answer (score 3):

First try *man curses*, then *man ncurses* if that fails.   Once you have found the curses documentation, the function you want is *insstr*, or possibly *inch*:

> These routines insert a character string (as many  characters  as  will
>          fit on the line) before the character under the cursor.  All characters
>          to the right of the cursor are shifted right with  the  possibility  of
>          the  rightmost  characters on the line being lost

```
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    initscr();
    printw("Welcome");
    refresh();
    sleep(2);
    insstr("\rHello, world. ");
    refresh();
    sleep(10);
    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: My C compiler can't find `ncurses.h`, so I can't try it. Upvoted for providing documentation though.

Comment: Unless this is a heavily text-based application I wouldn't suggest using curses.

Comment: @Dejvid It's often ncurses/ncurses.h or ncursesw/ncurses.h

Comment: Had no luck with this unfortunatelly. Tried `#include "ncursesw/ncurses.h"` , `#include "ncurses/ncurses.h"` , `#include <ncurses/ncurses.h>` and `#include <ncursesw/ncurses.h>` but nothing worked.

Comment: @Dejvid Do you run a Debian-based Linux distribution (Debian, Ubuntu, Mint)?